# How to create a scala.collection.immutable.Seq from a Java List in Java?

Tags: java, scala, akka

I'm trying to get Akka going in my Java project, and I'm hung up on a small issue with the Seq type(s) from Scala.  I'm able to convert my Java List of ActorRef into a scala.collection.Seq, but the Akka API I'm trying to use requires a scala.collection.immutable.Seq.  How can I make one?

Code:

```
static class Router extends UntypedLoadBalancer {
    private final InfiniteIterator<ActorRef> workers;

    public Router(List<ActorRef> workers) {
        Seq workerSeq = asScalaBuffer(workers);

        // how to get from the scala.collection.Seq above to the instance of
        // scala.collection.immutable.Seq required by CyclicIterator below?
        this.workers = new CyclicIterator<ActorRef>();
    }

    public InfiniteIterator<ActorRef> seq() {
        return workers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer` to convert the Java `List` to a Scala `Buffer`, which has a `toList` method, and a Scala `List` is a `collection.immutable.Seq`.

Comment: Picked this one as it answered my specific question more closely.  The line I ended up with was: new CyclicIterator<ActorRef>((Seq<ActorRef>) asScalaBuffer(workers).toList());

Comment: as of 2024 the JavaConversion is deprecated, use the scala.jdk.CollectionConverters instead. See the related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081253/upgrade-project-to-scala-2-13-javaconversions-is-not-a-member-of-package-collec.

Answer (score 4):

The [akka Java documentation for routers](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.3/java/routing.html) as well as the ScalaDoc for [CyclicIterator](http://akka.io/api/akka/1.1.3/#akka.routing.CyclicIterator) both suggest that the CyclicIterator constructor takes a List.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess I was mistaking immutable.Seq for a concrete type!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(list.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`scala.collection.JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterableConverter(workers).asScala().toSeq()`

Answer (score 0):

Since `scala` `2.12.0` `JavaConversions` is marked deprecated

```scala
@deprecated("use JavaConverters", since="2.12.0")
object JavaConversions extends WrapAsScala with WrapAsJava
```

so one should use `JavaConverters`

```scala
scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(list.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
```

or idiomatically

```scala
scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIterator(list.iterator()).toSeq();
```