# Clojure to Scala type conversions

Tags: scala, clojure

I'm having trouble converting a Clojure Seq to a Scala Seq. it seems like there should be an easy way to do this.

```
(let [animals ["dog" "cat" "pig"]]
  (to-scala-seq animals))
```

My goal is to use [twitter's algebird](https://github.com/twitter/algebird) in a Clojure project.

Comment: Are you trying to define `to-scala-seq`? If so, you should show what you have.

Answer (score 4):

Because Clojure and Scala both run on the JVM, this is fairly straight-forward:

```
 (ns scala-from-clojure.core
   (:import (scala.collection JavaConversions)))

 (defn to-scala-seq [coll]
   (-> coll JavaConversions/asScalaBuffer .toList))
```

At the REPL

```
user=> (use 'scala-from-clojure.core)
nil
user=> (to-scala-seq [1 2 3])
#<$colon$colon List(1, 2, 3)>
user=> (instance? scala.collection.immutable.Seq *1)
true
```

See

[How to create a scala.collection.immutable.Seq from a Java List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784593/how-to-create-a-scala-collection-immutable-seq-from-a-java-list-in-java)