# Syntax for Calling a variable-length parameter Scala function from Java?

Tags: java, scala, cross-language, variadic-functions

I have a Scala class whose constructor takes a variable-length parameter list.

```
case class ItemChain(items: Item*)
```

From Scala it can be called like so

```
ItemChain(Item(), Item())
```

I can't figure out the syntax for calling it from Java. If I do this

```
new ItemChain(new Item(), new Item())
```

I get a compiler error that says this line does not match the signature `scala.collection.seq<Item>`.

I can directly instantiate the Scala sequence object from Java.

```
new scala.collection.Seq<Item>()
```

But I can't figure out how to subsequently add my two `Item` instances to it. If I create a Java `List` of `Item`s and cast it to`scala.collection.Seq` I get a runtime error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scala, but it sounds like Scala uses it own class to marshall arguments in a variable-length function.  This is different from Java, which passes them as an array.

Comment: It looks like the simplest way to get a Seq from java is to use [JavaConversions][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784593/how-to-create-a-scala-collection-immutable-seq-from-a-java-list-in-java

Comment: `@scala.annotation.varargs` can usually help in situations like this, but not for constructors, and apparently not for `ItemChain.apply`, although you don't get an error if you put it in from of the case class definition (which is a little surprising to me). Put it on a `create` method in the companion object and you should be good to go, though.

Comment: @DPM You should post your comment as the answer.

Comment: I did, stackoverflow auto-converted it to a comment because it was short :) Looks like he got what he needed, which is what matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import static scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

...

new ItemChain(asScalaBufferConverter(asList(new Item(), new Item())).asScala());
```