# Upgrade project to Scala 2.13: JavaConversions is not a member of package collectio

Tags: scala, maven, twirl

I want to upgrade Scala version in multimodule maven project from 2.11 to 2.13. I changed all Scala version and Scala suffix version in pom.xml, updated the dependency version. I got next error in compilation:

```
 \target\generated-sources\twirl\txt\template.template.scala:12: object JavaConversions is not a member of package collection
```

In target folder I found compiled object of twirl template:

```
import _root_.play.twirl.api.JavaScript
import _root_.play.twirl.api.Xml
....
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object analyze_template extends _root_.play.twirl.api.BaseScalaTemplate[pla
```

From twirl template:

```
@(sourceIncrementName: String, sourceSnapshotName: String)
```

Could you tell me how to resolve it?

In maven I have scala-maven-plugin and twirl plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Xms128m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                        <arg>-explaintypes</arg>
                        <arg>-feature</arg>
                        <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
                    </args>
                    <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                    <scalaVersion>2.13</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>com.jakewharton.twirl</groupId>
           <artifactId>twirl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.0</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>compile</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```

And twirl dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>twirl-api_2.13</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Replace with `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`

Comment: @MarioGalic Thank you for response but I cant replace it because file with imports JavaConversions is in folder  target/generated-sources. And recompile every times.

Comment: This plugin is outdated - author hasn't updated it for Scala 2.13 (see deps in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.twirl/twirl-maven-plugin/1.2.0). So you have to fork and update it, or change the build tool, or write your own plugin which would hook after source code generation to edit the sources.

Comment: The use of `JavaConversions` was always a bad idea and discouraged, they were deprecated on `2.12` and finally removed on `2.13`. If this code is autogenerated, you simply can not upgrade until the plugin fixes this error, you may want to open an issue _(or maybe a PR)_ on the original project.

Answer (score 5):

As of Scala 2.13, the object **JavaConverters** in **scala.collection** package has been deprecated. You have to use **scala.jdk.CollectionConverters** henceforth. You can find the full documentation [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.2/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html)